# Unity возврат структуры из метода

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
private Vector3 Position()
{
    if (isLocal)
        return transform.localPosition;
    else
        return transform.position;
}
```

вот пример метода, я хочу узнать что он вернёт, копию структуры или саму структуру и если он вернёт копию то как мне получить сам объект

Answer (score 0):

Vector3 это структура, а не объект. Когда речь идёт о структуре или базовых типах, вы всегда получаете "копию", а не ссылку. Но если вы хотите отслеживать структуру или переменную базового типа подобно объекту с помощью [указателей](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types) и операций * и & вы можете узнать её адрес в памяти и обращаться к нему.

Comment: 'private Vector3 Position
    {
        get
        {
            if (isLocal)
                return transform.localPosition;
            else
                return transform.position;
        }
        set
        {
            if (isLocal)
                transform.localPosition = value;
            else
                transform.position = value;
        }
    }'  если я добавлю сеттер, в таком случае если я задаю значение Position, то получается я его задам и для оригинального transform.position?

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема задавать позицию напрямую gameObject? Во имя чего все эти пляски с бубном?

Comment: чтобы локальную и глобальную позиции объекта можно было бы менять через 1 метод.

Comment: На кой фиг тебе для этого вообще нужен целый отдельный метод? Абсурд какой-то! Напиши вопрос по люцки... 1 желаемый результат 2 то что получается (не желаемый) 3 код. Оту этот вокруг, да около полная муть.

Comment: Извините за неправильно поставленный вопрос, я уже решил проблему)) мне надо было уточнить, все получается, я просто писал компонент для перемещения объекта. Когда isLocal == true, то объект перемещается относительно родительского объекта, а когда isLocal == false то относительно сцены.